# Compass sprites hover state

Tags: css, compass-sass

I'm using compass and I've got my compass sprites working just fine.  The page loads and my images appear using the compass generated sprite.  My question is how do I now set a hover on these?  I'm new to compass so I don't understand how this is supposed to work and the compass documentation isn't helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what compass does is actually take all your separate images, turn them into one sprite and give you the css background positions for each icon so you paste that in your stylesheet.

If you want hover states for your buttons, you first need to create the hover icons. They should be included in the first sprite (or can be in a different one, as long as you then call the correct file). Compass will then give you the position for these "hover state" icons, and all you have to do is copy those positions and paste them in your css stylesheet for your hover state. For example:

```
// your normal icon: 
.icon {
      background-image: url(yourimage.png); 
      background-position:-100px -100px;
}

// your hover icon - position for hover state image: 
.icon:hover {
      background-image: url(yourimage.png); 
      background-position:-200px -100px;
}
```

Comment: Okay this works in that I now have my hover so thank you!  A new question is now I see the image "slide" when I hover instead of an instant replacement as I would see not using a sprite.

Answer (score 21):

Adding hovers to your sprites is very easy, just put "_hover" (or "_active", or "_target") in the image filename and let compass generate the sprite map for you =D.

Comment: I disagree. Compass simply adds a `:hover` selector and changes the background position. Why is this bad? Because on iOS `:hover` is triggered before the click event, so you will see the hover style for a brief moment before the page changes. Check out [How to deal with :hover on touch screen devices](http://www.prowebdesign.ro/how-to-deal-with-hover-on-touch-screen-devices/) for more info

Answer (score 1):

You should create your sprite sheet manually like this...

```
$sprite-map: sprite-map("your_sprite_folder_here/*.png")

i
    background: $sprite-map
    display: inline-block


@each $icon in sprite_names($sprite-map)
    .icn-#{$icon}
        background-position: sprite-position($sprite-map, $icon)
            +sprite-dimensions($sprite-map, $icon)
```

Then say you have 2 sprites in that folder... cats.png and cats-hover.png
To use them you would use an i element(can make this a class or whatever you want)

```
<i class=".icn-cats"></i>
```

To add the hover...

```
.icn-cats
    &:hover
        background-position: sprite-position($sprite-map, cats-hover)
```

I'm almost positive there is a way to automatically generate the hover state but I havent really put much time into figuring it out.